# Can I watch avi/mp4 files from a Mac on a TV set with an USB plug

Tags: macos, usb, video, tv

Note : this older [question](https://superuser.com/questions/294898/watching-dvds-from-a-pc-on-a-tv)([Watching DVDs from a PC on a TV](https://superuser.com/questions/294898/watching-dvds-from-a-pc-on-a-tv)) is an almost-duplicate of my question here, except that it's for a Windows computer instead of a Macintosh, and all the answers given there are helpful only for PCs as far as I can see.

A neighbor kindly gave me an old TV set (the trademark is Philips, model is UVSH 14PT1501/12) that he no longer uses, and now I can watch cable TV with it.
Since there is a USB plug on the adaptor (the trademark is CGV ; model is Etimo 1T-2, see image below), I wonder if I can also use it to watch mp4 or avi files from my computer ?
I tried inserting my USB key into the plug and turning the tv on but it seems my key was not detected.

Additional data printed on the Adaptor box :

```
Etimo 1T-2, DV3 
PCB : V1.7 2016.03.29 
Decoder : MSTAR MSD7801 
Tuner : Maxlinear MXL608
```

[image of adaptor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj8PX.jpg)

Comment: What is the make and model of that box with the usb port? Also the same for TV. No way anyone can answer this as currently written.

Comment: @Moab Thx for your feedback, I've filled those details now

Comment: Do you know what the usb port is to be used for, I can find no user manual.

Comment: @Moab I have no idea, which is why I asked this question here

Comment: Unless someone has that box and uses the usb port and posts an answer or comment, there may be no answer otherwise.